# Insert data to 2 table on the same form

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have 3 tables:

```
Tbl_1. Tour_Journey

id | title | tour_id | hotel_list | content | 
----------------------------------------

Tbl_2. Hotel

id | hotel_name | rating | address |
------------------------------------

Tbl_3. Hotel_in_Journey

id | journey_id | hotel_id | hotel_name |
---------------------------------------
```

`hotel_list` field of Tbl_1 retrieved data from Tbl_2 and insert to Tbl_3 
and journey_id.Tbl_3 = id.Tbl_1

How to insert data into Tbl_1 and Tbl_3 on the same web form? Or step-by-step?
On web form, hotel_list field can choose multiple value but I don't known how to insert multiple rows into Tbl_3?

Comment: What programming language are you using?  Do you have some existing code you can show us?